# ODBC interface/driver written in Java

Tags: java, odbc

I'm looking for a way to expose my Java EE application server through an ODBC connection. That is; I need to serve data from my AS to applications which connect to it with ODBC.

This would probably mean I have to write up a custom ODBC driver in Java, which seems to be a daunting task.

Anyone here with experience of this? Have this been done before? Any libraries to start out with? Am I crazy?

EDIT:
It's a matter of integration between my appserver and *clients* reading data from it through ODBC. Specifically in it's first iteration, Microsoft SharePoint. I already have a JAX-WS, but unfortunately that is a no go for SharePoint/Cudes/MS Analysis services/MS Reporting services etc.

The data would be represented basically as one flat table. The problem I'm having goes to the low end stuff. Protocol, negotiation, authentication. If I come to the point where I can accept an ODBC connection and push tabular data, I'm home free..

Comment: I don't follow. Elaborate on what you want to do.

Comment: Sounds a bit crazy to me. :) A huge task. Can you make data available via web services instead? That is more in line with typical Java EE AS approaches.

Comment: Yes, web service is already there, unfortunately ODBC is needed aswell.

Answer (score 4):

Elijah:

One suggestion is to use an SDK to build a driver. 90% of the work is already done in the SDK. I work for Simba Technologies and we do exactly that.  Help people like you build ODBC drivers in C++, Java and C#.  Take a look at our website www.simba.com

Suzanne

Answer (score 2):

Run a separate database to which your clients can connect. Your server just pushes data to this database.  But, this will not be a request-response based mechanism.  Server will have to populate tables before it anticipates client requests. 
You might have to manage authentication/authorization by creating a db user for each client and then have a table for each db user and restricting db user to only his table.

Not that elegant, huh?

Comment: Doable, yes. But not for me. The amount of data required for that is just huge. It need to be request based and limit on selection. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try an in-memory database such as [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) which supports ODBC and push your data into that.

Comment: Very interesting, will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your useful propositions.
However, I ended up building a JDBC driver and will distribute a generic ODBC-JDBC bridge driver ontop of that.

I will probably use this bridge:
http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-jdbc-st/

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDB provides a object orientated API, for C++. This could be a star point: http://simpledb.sourceforge.net/